# I want to write file for every elemnt in the array using php

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I'm tring to write file for every element in `$filename` array.

Error:

> Notice: Array to string conversion in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\insertSalestest.php on line 22
>
> Notice: Array to string conversion in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\insertSalestest.php on line 22
>
> Notice: Array to string conversion in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\insertSalestest.php on line 22
>
> Notice: Array to string conversion in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\insertSalestest.php on line 22 {"state":105}

PHP code :

```
<?php 
include "connection.php.php";

$sucess = 105;
$fail = 107;

$result;

$base = array("my", "litte", "array", 2);

$filename = array("my", "litte", "array", 2);

foreach($base as $option) {
    $sql = "INSERT INTO sale_image(sale_id, img_url) VALUES ('1','$option');";
    $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
}

foreach($filename as $value) {
    $imageNow = time();
    $new_imageFilename = $imageNow."_".$filename;
    $binary=base64_decode($value);
    header('Content-Type: bitmap; charset=utf-8');
    $file = fopen('files/'.$new_imageFilename, 'wb');
    fwrite($file, $binary);
    fclose($file);      
}

$jsonResult = '{"state":';
if($result){
    $jsonResult.= $sucess;
}else {
    $jsonResult.= $fail;
}
$jsonResult .="}";
print_r($jsonResult);
?>
```

Comment: I think the error comes from here: `$new_imageFilename = $imageNow."_".$filename;` You are concatenating an array to a string

Comment: You're treating `$filename` as an array when you declare the loop and then as a string inside it. I'm pretty sure you mean `$value` the second time.

Comment: can you explain this `header('Content-Type: bitmap; charset=utf-8');` please...

Comment: Can you help me what to edit exactly?, because i tried to edit the code more than once and everytime it's the same and it writes the file only once

Comment: @marvinIsSacul 
i just was searching for how to write String as a image and i got this code, i'm just new in php and i'm a bit confused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are not trying to send raw headers to the browser yourself then you don't need to use `header('Content-Type: bitmap; charset=utf-8');`.

Anyways I think I understand what you want so try this...

```
<?php 
include "connection.php.php";

$sucess = 105;
$fail = 107;

$result;

$base = array("my", "litte", "array", 2);

$filename = array("my", "litte", "array", 2);

    foreach($base as $option) {
        $sql = "INSERT INTO sale_image(sale_id, img_url) VALUES ('1','$option');";
        $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
    }

    foreach($filename as $value) {
        $imageNow = time();
        $new_imageFilename = $imageNow . "_" . $value; // use $value instead of $filename - because $filename is an array
        $binary=base64_decode($value);
            /* header('Content-Type: bitmap; charset=utf-8'); */ // don't see the need
        $file = fopen('files/' . $new_imageFilename, 'wb');
        fwrite($file, $binary);
        fclose($file);      
    }

    $jsonResult = '{"state":';
    if($result){
        $jsonResult.= $sucess;
    }else {
        $jsonResult.= $fail;
    }
    $jsonResult .="}";
    print_r($jsonResult);
```

Comment: Thank you so much, you saved my day.